# It seems that box-sizing: border-box is not working

Tags: html, css, border-box

I've never came across this issue, but in a nutshell I apply border box as my box-sizing to all the elements:

```
*, *:before, *:after {

      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box !important;
      box-sizing: border-box !important;
    }
```

I than have a responsive column layout, in this case 3 columns per row

```
<div class="row clearfix">
   <div class="column span-4-12 property">
      <p>..</p>
   </div>

   <!-- more divs here -->
</div>
```

All spans nicely across 3 columns until I add margin to .property div, now usually because of border-box this would simply add margin between the columns and leave them 3 in a row, but now for some reason 3rd column is pushed to a new row, I honestly don't understand why, am I missing something?

Here is live example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NmrZZ/

Comment: Margin is not part of the `border-box` sizing. Thus `width:33.333%(3) + side margins > 100%`, so the last element is pushed to the next row

Comment: @ZachSaucier really, I swear it worked for me before, is there a way to apply such behaviour to margins as well?

Comment: You'll have to subtract the % margins from the width. In your case that would make the width 31.3333%

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Margin is not part of the box-model (whatever box-sizing you use), so it will always be in addition to the width + padding + border you've declared.

The image below (from the [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) article on this topic) illustrates the difference between the standard box-model and `box-sizing: border-box`:

[image]

The best advice I can give is to avoid margins for your grid entirely, and to keep it separate from your presentation. This means more markup, but will save you headaches and make things much easier to maintain. Check out [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/Zf57L/) of your example. The amended CSS:

```
.span-4-12 {
    width: 33.33%;
    padding-left: 2%;
}

.property {
    background: white;
}
```

And the new markup will be:

```
<div class="column span-4-12">
    <div class="property">
        <p>Some text 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a float clear problem. Instead of float you can use inline-block as float is outdated. Most people now use `display:inline-block` as there is no need to write `clear` for separate line.

**Refer:**

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box !important;
 box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

body {
    background: grey;
}
}

.row {
 clear: both;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear:both;
}
.clear {
    zoom:1;
}

.column {
 display: inline-block;
 }

.span-4-12 {
 width: 30%; 
}

.property {
    background: white;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
   <div class="column span-4-12 property">
      <p>Some text 1</p>
   </div>
    
    <div class="column span-4-12 property">
      <p>Some text 2</p>
   </div>
    
    <div class="column span-4-12 property">
      <p>Some text 3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced a similar problem although I didn't use any margin. When I  didn't determine a height for a div in grid, onclick animation on a button  effected the div size and move things around even if I tried box-sizing:border-box.Setting a height for the div containing the button worked. Button re-size animation works but the surrounding div doesn't expand. This was the solution in my case. So the problem might not be margins!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem today.

I added the following `CSS` code at the top of the component `CSS` file to reset it, and the column elements won't go to a new line anymore:

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: omg, the format...
the css code is 
<star> { box-sizing:border-box;}