# Why is border-sizing: border-box; not working?

Tags: css, padding, border-box

I want to animate the width of the div, starting from 0. But because of the padding the div never will be less than the padding I set. I tried using `border-sizing: border-box;` but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

[Here](https://codepen.io/jnhltmn/pen/mdwGvMy) is my Pen.

```css
font-size: 14px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #fff;
background: #E2001A;
position: absolute;
margin: 85px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 8px 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 2px;
```

Comment: Checkout this question, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/22253627/10330372

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
.hotspotCaption1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;  
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hotspotCaption2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;  
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<div class="hotspotCaption1">Consectetur Purus Fermentum Commodo</div><br>

<div class="hotspotCaption2">Consectetur Purus Fermentum Commodo</div>
```

your code is working properly but you have given very little width to the div which you can realize just give more width and create two different divs one with box-sizing and the other without box-sizing.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your div inside another one and just animate the width of the parent div.

```css
.hotspotCaption {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  background: #E2001A;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.outer-wrp {
  margin: 85px;
  width: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrp">
  <div class="hotspotCaption">
    Consectetur Purus Fermentum Commodo
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution that I have found and tested is this one:

```css
.hotspotCaption {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  background: #E2001A;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 85px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 0px;
  animation-duration: 1s; /* Change duration */
  animation-name: appear; /* Change its name */
  animation-iteration-count: 1; /* Change how many times it repeats */
  animation-direction: normal; /* Change its direction */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* specifies a style when the animation stops */
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    padding: 0;
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 8px 10px;
    width: 255px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hotspotCaption">Consectetur Purus Fermentum Commodo</div>
```

Also, here is a Pen I made: [Link](https://codepen.io/MadScientist_64/pen/LYLJaVV).

It did not work because `box-sizing: border-box;` does not affect padding in the way that you want, and there was no `transition` or `animation` applied in the first place. The thing is to make an animation that *includes* padding in its start position, and makes it zero. Hope this solution helped you!